# 401: Authorization Required when retrieving Request Token from Twitter API

Tags: python, django, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working on a Django application which retrieves some data from Twitter, and I need to work with requests manually since it's for an exam whose main focus is for us to learn how to work with network protocols such as HTTP. So please don't suggest me to use a wrapper.

My issue is that whenever I try to request the initial request token (with a POST request that is referenced in this [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) and also [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/request_token)), I receive  a 401: Authorization Required and I have no clue what could be causing it, since I'm including the Authorization header in exactly the format required by the docs I've linked. It may be that while working with `urllib` I don't manage to make the POST request as I wanted, or perhaps there's something wrongin how I made the signature/where I've placed it in the header, even though in my opinion it should be alright.

Here's my code to handle the request to "sign in with Twitter":

```
def sign(request):
    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
    #I store consumer key, consumer secret and callback url in a txt
    dir_path = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))
    with open(path.join(dir_path, 'credentials.txt'), 'r') as TweetCred:
        creds = TweetCred.read().split(linesep)
    oauth_consumer_key = creds[0].split()[1]
    oauth_callback = creds[1].split()[1]
    consumer_secret = creds[2].split()[1]

    oauth_nonce = ''.join(SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(32))
    #Desperate to understand what could be causing the error, I tried to use an integer timestamp sinceit was integer in the examples
    oauth_timestamp = int(time.time())
    parameter_string =  (   'oauth_nonce=' + urllib.parse.quote(oauth_nonce, safe='') +
                            '&oauth_callback=' + urllib.parse.quote(oauth_callback, safe='') + 
                            '&oauth_signature_method=' + urllib.parse.quote('HMAC-SHA1', safe='') +
                            '&oauth_timestamp=' + urllib.parse.quote(str(oauth_timestamp), safe='') +
                            '&oauth_consumer_key=' + urllib.parse.quote(oauth_consumer_key, safe='') +
                            '&oauth_version=' + urllib.parse.quote('1.0', safe='')
                        )

    sigbase = 'POST' + '&' + urllib.parse.quote(url, safe='') + '&' + urllib.parse.quote(parameter_string, safe='')
    signkey = urllib.parse.quote(consumer_secret, safe='') + '&'

    key = bytes(signkey, 'UTF-8')
    base = bytes(sigbase, 'UTF-8')
    digester = hmac.new(key, base, hashlib.sha1)
    binsignature = digester.digest()
    signature = urllib.parse.quote(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(binsignature), safe='')    
    oauth_header =  ('Oauth ' + 'oauth_nonce="%s", ' % urllib.parse.quote(oauth_nonce, safe='') + 
                                'oauth_callback="%s", ' % urllib.parse.quote(oauth_callback, safe='') +
                                'oauth_signature_method="%s", ' % urllib.parse.quote('HMAC-SHA1', safe='') +
                                'oauth_timestamp="%s", ' %urllib.parse.quote(str(oauth_timestamp), safe='')  +
                                'oauth_consumer_key="%s", ' % urllib.parse.quote(oauth_consumer_key, safe='') +
                                'oauth_version="%s", ' % urllib.parse.quote('1.0', safe='') +
                                'oauth_signature="%s"' % signature
                    )
    headers = {'Authorization': oauth_header}
    #urllib wants a body to know that it's a POST, at least that's what the docs said, so I'm providing an empty one
    values = {}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode('ascii')
    TokenRequest = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
    try:
        print('opening request token url...')
        with urllib.request.urlopen(TokenRequest) as response:
            if response.getcode() != 200:
                print('Response is %s' % response.getcode())
                return HttpResponse('Error in getting the token from Twitter, please try again...')
            body = loads(response.read())
            if body['oauth_callback_confirmed'] != 'true':
                print('oauth_callback not confirmed')
                return HttpResponse('Error in getting the token from Twitter, please try again...')
            oauth_token = body['oauth_token']
            oauth_token_secret = body['oauth_token_secret']
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
        #my program always ends up here, catches the exception and returns the line below
        return HttpResponse('Error %s in getting the token from Twitter, please try again...' % err)

    print('Successfully retrieved request token! Redirecting...')
    loggee = User.objects.Create()
    loggee.oauth_token = oauth_token
    loggee.oauth_token_secret = oauth_token_secret
    return HttpResponseRedirect('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token='+oauth_token)
```

Any help will be appreciated! I'm quite in a hurry and I really can't wrap my head around this!

Comment: Why don't you use `oauth2` to handle the authentication part? It is standard twitter authentication code. you can find an example [here](https://github.com/vaulstein/twitterApiForHumans/blob/master/quickstart.py)

Comment: No, that's not the "standard twitter authentication code", it's just a third party wrapper. From [Twitter's developer API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request): The oauth_version parameter should always be 1.0 for any request sent to the Twitter API.

Comment: Check this out - The docs mention using [oauth2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/single-user)

Comment: Ok, it seems oauth2 implements Oauth 1.0, thus it should be alright. Nevertheless, I need to work manually with requests instead of making the library "handle the heavy lifting of signing requests", and it should work the same since I'm following the protocol. I'm editing the question though, I fixed a typo in the header and now have a different error.

Comment: Edited. Can't understand why my authorization isn't accepted.

Comment: Could you share a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) of your headers without you consumer key and token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165292/discussion-between-vaulstein-and-earendil-baggins).

Comment: it's the oauth_header variable in the code. Also I saw that my signature had a '=' character in it and I URLencoded it but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your signature base string needs to be sorted lexigraphically (which means alphabetically for all intents), before you calculate your signature (ref: [Creating a signature](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html))

Therefore your parameter string needs to be:

```
parameter_string =  (    
        'oauth_callback=' + urllib.parse.quote(oauth_callback, safe='') +
        '&oauth_consumer_key=' + urllib.parse.quote(oauth_consumer_key, safe='') +
        '&oauth_nonce=' + urllib.parse.quote(oauth_nonce, safe='') +
        '&oauth_signature_method=' + urllib.parse.quote('HMAC-SHA1', safe='') +
        '&oauth_timestamp=' + urllib.parse.quote(str(oauth_timestamp), safe='') +
        '&oauth_version=' + urllib.parse.quote('1.0', safe='')
     )
```